# Modify DomainService code?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

How can one modify DomainService code without the custom code being overwritten?

Is there a way to put the custom code in a seperate class file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the insert/update/delete generated code? You are *supposed* to modify and expand this code for your specific needs. View this code as a suggested starting point on which to build your custom functionality.

If you are talking about the classes generated by the data model, then consider expanding the partial classes with metadata: http://www.nikhilk.net/RIA-Services-Fluent-Metadata-API.aspx

For a more detailed sample, see the [Book Club RIA Services Application](http://www.nikhilk.net/RIAServices-BookClub-TOC.aspx) tutorial (code and videos) by Nikhil Kothari.

Comment: No, I'm referring to the Get methods of the DomainService. I have associations set up within the Entity Model, but the DomainService is agnostic of those relationships. Therefore, I have to decorate the Property within the "ugly buddy" class of the DomainServices metadata with an "Include" attribute. The Fluent API may work, but I feel that the DomainService missed the bar when it comes to extensibility, hopefully v-next will resolve the extensibility limitations. EF is a great example of an extensible framework (because it generates partial classes from the get-go).

Comment: The way I understand it is that `[Include]` only applies to data objects send to the client. You should not need it on the server side.

Comment: The [Include] is needed within the Server's metadata file because wihtout it you can not retrieve associated entities.